# How to compare 2 MS Excel file structure(Columns) using SSIS

Tags: ssis, excel-2010, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

I have a requirement in which I need to compare columns of 2 Excel files.
If columns are matched, then proceed with next steps of SSIS package. If columns are not matched, SSIS package should stop.
Please help.

Comment: You need to use `GetOleDbSchemaTable`. Here are some examples. Try these and come back with any specific problems. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/318452, https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1674/retrieve-excel-schema-using-sql-integration-services-ssis/, http://www.proteanit.com/b/2008/03/05/code-to-query-excel-schema-in-ssis-script-component/

Comment: Thanks Nick, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

1. Import data into SQL table.
2. Compare columns
3. then proceed based on match or no match.
   Do i miss anything here

Comment: Thanks Ken, yes, I was particularly looking for implementation of step 1 mentioned by you above. Its done. Thanks much !!